# Nifty mBaaSのデータストアに管理画面でレコードの追加が出来ません

Tags: baas

[Nifty mBaaS](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/)のデータストアにPCを使いレコードを追加したいのですが出来ません。
管理画面でデータストアのところで新しいレコードのボタンを押すと、既存のレコードの上に行ができるのですが、カスケード状態で何も入力できません。
ObjectIDとか出てます。
どうすれば追加出来るでしょうか。

[このチュートリアル](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/tutorial/monaca_quiz_01.html)を参考にクイズアプリを作っています。
アプリ側でクイズを作成し、バックエンド側でデータストアの場所にアプリで作成した問題を確認する所まで出来ています。
次は問題をパソコンで作成し、バックエンド側に一気に登録したいのですが、上記の問題が発生しました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: バックエンドにはどのようなサービスを使っていますか？ もう少し具体的で、自分で試した事とその結果などもないと、回答は得られにくいです。（クイズ位でしたら静的なファイルとして`json`形式などでどこかに置いておくだけでもよさそうですが、どうでしょうか。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。
バックエンドのサービスはニフティクラウドのモバイルバックエンドです。
アプリでクイズを作成しバックエンド側でデータストアの場所にアプリで作成した問題を確認しました。　
データストアの場所でPCを使い問題を追加していきたいのですが
新しいレコードのボタンを押しても　新しいレコードが追加できません。
どのようにすればレコードPCで追加して、アプリ側で追加した問題を表示していけるかわかりません。
わかりにくいかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 「新しいレコードのボタンを押しても　新しいレコードが追加できません」この部分をもう少し具体的に説明出来ますか？ 参照しているドキュメントは[これ](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/datastore/basic_usage_javascript.html)ですか？

Comment: http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/tutorial/monaca_quiz_01.htmlドキュメントはこれです。 これでは、アプリ側だけしか問題の作り方はないです。 バックエンドの管理画面から問題を作りたいです。 バックエンドの管理画面でデータストアのところで新しいレコード押すと 既存の問題の上に行ができるんですがカスケード状態で何も入力できません ObjectIDとか出てます。

Answer (score 1):

GUI操作でのトラブルは状況が伝わり難いので、回答が付きづらいですね。以下は一般論に近いですが、参考になれば。

#### 管理画面での追加方法

[公式のドキュメント](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/datastore/basic_usage_javascript.html#%E3%83%AC%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)にスクリーンショット付きで解説されていますので、まずはこれと見比べながら操作してみるのがよいでしょう。
それで駄目でしたら、mBaaSの障害情報なども確認が必要かもしれません。
また、使用している[ブラウザがサポートされているか](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/dashboard/browser.html)どうかも念の為。

これらを確認の上、解決しないようならば質問の編集で状況を追記して下さい。スクリーンショットなどがあるほうが良いかもしれません。
公式の[サポート](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/support.htm)や、[コミュニティ](https://github.com/NIFTYCloud-mbaas/UserCommunity)もあります。

#### 用意したファイルからインポートする方法

これも[公式のドキュメント](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/datastore/basic_usage_javascript.html#%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)に解説がありますから、参照して下さい。
うまくいかない場合は、エラー内容なども細かく質問に追記して下さい。
（最初の質問とずれていくようでしたら、別の質問にした方がよいかもしれないですね。）